# Disable directory listing in artifactory

Tags: artifactory

I need to Disable directory listing in .
Any suggestions  ?
I tried to search for result in google but didn't find any
I only found a way that you can block the connection to the URL but this isn't what i need

Comment: ** Jfrog Artifactory 
** the url block : (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48763696/jfrog-artifactory-disable-directory-listing).

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to disable the directory-listing for particular users, then you can achieve this by adding providing the repository path exclude-pattern at the permission target end.

In the below example, I have enabled anonymous user access only to specific packages, Please refer below steps for the same:

1. I have created a PyPI local repository, deployed python packages into it as shown in the below screenshot:
   [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rnd8P.png)
2. After this, created a permissions target to restrict access to a specific folder called st-fraud-infra to the anonymous user. Hence added st-fraud-infra/** as a exclude pattern, kindly refer to the below screenshot for the same:
   [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/351IN.png)
3. Add anonymous users from the Users tab and provided appropriate permissions based on your requirement.
   [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LdIdV.png)
4. Once you saved the permission target while accessing the Artifactory through the anonymous user, I could not see the excluded folder which is st-fraud-infra.
   [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EQ1Ws.png)